# Getting new Twitter API consumer and secret keys

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working on a Twitter project where I want to use OAuth but I don't know where to get the consumer and secret keys.

How can I get these?

Answer (score 106):

To get Consumer Key & Consumer Secret, you have to create an app in Twitter via

https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps

Then you'll be taken to a page containing Consumer Key & Consumer Secret.

Hopefully this information will clarify OAuth essentials for Twitter:

1. Create a Twitter account if you don't already have one
2. Visit 'https://apps.twitter.com' and follow the required prompts to create a developer project (Twitter requires you to answer some questions before they will approve your account.  Approval was nearly instant in my case.)
3. Requesting the API key and secret via the Developer Portal causes Twitter to produce the following three things:

- API key (this is your 'consumer key')
- API secret key (this is your 'consumer secret')
- Bearer token

4. Next, visit the 'Authentication Tokens' area of the Developer Portal and generate an 'Access token & secret'.  This will provide you with the following two items:

- Access token (this is your 'token key')
- Access token secret (this is your 'token secret')

5. The consumer key, consumer secret, token key, and token secret should be sufficient to do Twitter API calls (they were for me).

Comment: This worked, the answer by Pankaj looks to be an older solution.

Comment: You would also need to add your phone number to profile, if you haven't, follow this: https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web

Comment: I can not find  'Authentication Tokens' area of the Developer Portal.

Answer (score 34):

1. Log into the [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/) section.

   - If you don't already have an account, you can login with your normal Twitter credentials
2. Go to "[Create an app](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new)"
3. Fill in the details of the application you'll be using to connect with the API

   - Your application **name must be unique.** If someone else is already using it, you won't be able to register your application until you can think of something that isn't being used.
4. Click on **Create your Twitter application**
5. Details of your new app will be shown along with your consumer key and consumer secret.
6. If you need access tokens, scroll down and click **Create my access token**

   - The page will then refresh on the "Details" tab with your new access tokens. You can recreate these at any time if you need to.

By default your apps will be granted for read-only access. To change this, go to the *Settings* tab and change the access level required in the "Application Type" section.

#### Existing apps

To get the consumer and access tokens for an existing application, go to [My applications](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) (which is available from the menu in the upper-right).

Comment: This was the most useful answer, thank you for being clear and simple !

Comment: UPVOTE! Best answer: simple, straightforward, concise, accurate, EFFECTIVE!

Answer (score 24):

*step 1*.Go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps

---

*step 2*.Create app(fill up the form)

---

*step 3*.Change permissions if necessary(depending if you want to just read,write or execute)

---

*step 4*.Go To API keys section and click generate ACCESS TOKEN.

---

5 years late to answer :)

Now you have these tokens which is all you need.

```
'oauth_access_token' => Access token
'oauth_access_token_secret' => Access token secret
'consumer_key' => API key
'consumer_secret' => API secret
```

Comment: At least someone explains that API key = consumerKey!

Comment: After hours of searching this is the first piece of knowledge I find that explains this relationship between access tokens, consumer keys, secrets, etc.  Twitter fail, Stack Overflow win.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly the pain i went through,thats the reason why i posted the answer even it was 5 years late.

Comment: please tell me one thing when i make request for example digits by twitter in my android app, then in place of api and secret should i use above two ('oauth_access_token', 'oauth_access_token_secret') or below two ('consumer_key', 'consumer_secret')

Answer (score 3):

Simply go here: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new Make sure you have logged in with your Twitter account - then create - even if your just entering random (Test) Content - create your  app - afterwards you will receive all the data you require :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps to list all your apps. Click on the desired app to get its consumer and secret key. If you didnt yet created any app then follow https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new to create new one.

Answer (score 3):

This slide show shows how to get both keys updated June 2013.

http://www.slideshare.net/Tweetganic/generate-twitter-applications

Answer (score 3):

From the Twitter FAQ:

Most integrations with the API will require you to identify your application to Twitter by way of an API key. On the Twitter platform, the term "API key" usually refers to what's called an OAuth consumer key. This string identifies your application when making requests to the API. In OAuth 1.0a, your "API keys" probably refer to the combination of this consumer key and the "consumer secret," a string that is used to securely "sign" your requests to Twitter.

Answer (score 2):

`consumer_key` = `API key`

`consumer_secret` = `API key secret`

Found it hidden in [Twitter API Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweets-and-users/quick-start/get-tweets)

[image: Twitter Docs screenshot]

Twitter's naming is just too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, from ***November 2018*** anyone who wants access Twitter’s APIs  must apply for a Twitter Development Account by visiting https://developer.twitter.com/. Once your application has been approved then only you'll be able to create Twitter apps.

Once the Twitter Developer Account is ready:

1) Go to https://developer.twitter.com/.

2) Click on **Apps** and then click on **Create an app**.

3) Provide an **App Name** & **Description**.

4) Enter a website name in the **Website URL** field.

5) Click on **Create**.

6) Navigate to your app, then click on **Details** and then go to **Keys and Tokens**.

Reference: http://www.technocratsid.com/getting-twitter-consumer-api-access-token-keys/