# How to set consumer key/secret pair in Twitter4J?

Tags: java, api, twitter, twitter4j

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("*********************")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******************************************")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("**************************************************")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******************************************");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```

What are the values in place of *?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Consumer Key and Consumer Secret are provided when you create your application at https://dev.twitter.com/apps. There is more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808855/getting-new-twitter-api-consumer-and-secret-keys). You then have to get the access token from your users.

The Twitter developer documentation has a description of the whole process, but it can be hard to know where to start. I suggest you look for guide like [this one](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/). (Understanding how OAuth works will make the whole process clearer.)